# how to add days to date variable on every ng-repeat loop in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-init

I have set date variable in "ng-init" directive and i want to add days to this date variable on every ng-repeat loop like below:

```html
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="n in myArr" ng-init="myDate=('07/25/2017'|date:addDays($index))">
    <td ng-bind="myDate"></td>
  </tr>
</table
```

Comment: What is the function **addDays** ?

Comment: it's just for example, it isn't a function.

Comment: what is your expected result?

Comment: e.g. : i have 3 object in array. so i expect in first row "myDate=07/25/2017", second row "myDate=07/26/2017" and third row "myDate=07/27/2017"

Comment: are these 25,26,and 27 from myArr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can instantiate your first date in the controler like this :

```
$scope.firstDate = new Date('07/25/2017');
```

And add days to it in the **ngRepeat** like this :

```
<tr ng-repeat="n in myArr" ng-init="myDate=(firstDate.setDate(firstDate.getDate() + 1)|date)">
```

And if you want your date with the format **mm/dd/yyyy**, you need to add at the end of your **ngInit** `:'M/d/yyyy'`, like this  (you can take a look at [the doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) for more information about date format) :

```
<tr ng-repeat="n in myArr" ng-init="myDate=(firstDate.setDate(firstDate.getDate() + 1)|date:'M/d/yyyy')">
```

But if you have other things to do with dates I think it could be a good idea to take a look at [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.firstDate = new Date('07/25/2017');
  $scope.myArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
});
```

```html
<script data-require="angular.js@1.5.x" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.5.11"></script>

<table ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <tr ng-repeat="n in myArr" ng-init="myDate=(firstDate.setDate(firstDate.getDate() + 1)|date)">
    <td ng-bind="myDate"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```